# How to get the current working directory of a process in FreeBSD in C?

Tags: c, freebsd

Currently I'm trying to port a terminal emulator written in C from Linux to FreeBSD.
But the terminal tries to get the current working directory (CWD) from the parent process.

It does this by accessing `/proc/$PID/cwd`.

Now I'm looking for a way to replace this functionalty with something that works on FreeBSD.

So how do I get the CWD from a process in FreeBSD?

Is there even a POSIX conform solution?

I know that I can get the CWD from my process with `getcwd` but I need the CWD of the parent process, where I only know the PID.

Comment: You mean [getcwd](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=getcwd&sektion=3) system call? Or you need a shell solution?

Comment: `getcwd` only gives the CWD of the running process not any process like the parent process.

Comment: Likely, on FreeBSD there's no instant facility to achieve the task. However using `fstat -p <pid>` or `lsof -p <pid>` you may get a report which contains `cwd` among other information. Check http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94357/find-out-current-working-directory-of-a-running-process

Comment: Grab the PID of the parent process, then use libkvm to grab the parent's kinfo_proc struct. The CWD of it should be in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, actually you have two possibilities. One of them is to use shell utilities like `lsof -p`, `fstat -p` (as I mentioned in the comment above) or another utility named `procstat` as described [here](http://lserinol.blogspot.ru/2009/05/getting-detailed-process-information-on.html). With `procstat` the solution will look like this:

```
procstat -f <pid> | awk '$3 == "cwd" { print $10 }'
```

another possible solution is to use [libprocstat](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=libprocstat&apropos=0&sektion=3&manpath=FreeBSD+9-current&format=html) library call, particularly `procstat_getfiles()` to get the complete info in your C program. Take a look at [procstat sources](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/freebsd/usr.bin/procstat/procstat_files.c#307) to get an example of API usage.